# How to cast an object in generic collection?

Tags: c#, reflection, collections, casting

I need to convert an object to a generic collection, look:

```
var currentEntityProperties = currentEntity.GetType().GetProperties();

foreach (var currentEntityProperty in currentEntityProperties)
{
    if (currentEntityProperty.PropertyType.GetInterfaces().Any(
                x => x.IsGenericType &&
                x.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(ICollection<>)))
    {
        var collectionType = currentEntityProperty.PropertyType.GetInterfaces().Where(
                                x => x.IsGenericType &&
                                x.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(ICollection<>)).First();

        var argumentType = collectionType.GetGenericArguments()[0];

        // now i need to convert the currentEntityProperty into a collection, something like that (this is wrong, so, what is thr right way?):
        var currentCollection = (ICollection<argumentType.GetType()>)currentEntityProperty.GetValue(currentEntity, null);
    }
}
```

How can i do this?

Obs: i need with this collection call the except method with another collection (this collection i get with the same way of the currentCollection, with a `anotherEntityProperty.GetValue(anotherEntity, null)`)

```
var itens = currentCollection.Except(anotherCollection);
```

Comment: What are you going to do with it afterwards? If you can tell us a bit more about the wider context, we may be able to provide an alternative approach.

Comment: And do you not know the type of `anotherCollection` either? Where are you getting that from? Can you make a single generic call with reflection earlier on? If you're using C# 4, dynamic typing could make this easier too.

Comment: The type of the anotherCollection i don't know neither, but i know that currentCollection and anotherCollection will have the same type. And i get the anotherCollection in the same way of that i get the currentCollection. `var anotherCollection = newEntityProperty.GetValue(newEntity, null);`.

Comment: @ViniciusOttoni since you're obviously proficient with reflection, why not call the method using reflection?

Comment: @phoog You mean, call Except method with reflection?

Comment: @ViniciusOttoni I did mean that, yes.

Comment: @phoog Well, i think something like: `var exceptMethod = typeof(ICollection<>).GetMethod("Except", BindingFlags.Instance);` but the exceptMethod is null, what i have to put in place of `ICollection<>`? Because the argument of the collection i just know at runtime.

Comment: @JonSkeet, did you find a way to do that?

Comment: @ViniciusOttoni: Do what, exactly? AS I say, if you've got C# 4, this can be really simple...

Comment: @JonSkeet I'm using c# 4, but i don't know the simple way that you talking about. Do you have a topic name, or a msdn link that can help me? Because the problem is that i know the type of the generic collection in runtime...

Comment: @ViniciusOttoni see my answer which explains how to call the method by reflection, and also gives a short example of `dynamic` (Jon Skeet's suggestion).

Comment: @ViniciusOttoni: Now I know you're using C# 4, I can post an answer using dynamic typing...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Dynamic typing lets you make the compiler and DLR do all the work here:

```
dynamic currentCollection = ...;
dynamic anotherCollection = ...;
dynamic items = Enumerable.Except(currentCollection, anotherCollection);
```

At execution time, that will do all the reflection work for you and pick the most appropriate type argument.

Comment: This is so beatiful! =P - I didn't knew this keyword `dynamic`. So, thank you Jon!

Comment: @ViniciusOttoni: It's worth learning about so you can use it *in moderation*. Note that this will end up throwing a binding exception if the "execution-time compiler" can't work out what to do.

Comment: Yes, i saw the danger if it is used without moderation, but if you know what are you doing, this can be beautiful =).

Answer (score 1):

For the Except extension method, you only need an `IEnumerable<T>`, which `ICollection<T>` implements. So you can cast your property to `IEnumerable<object>` (at least if T is a reference type).

EDIT:

If you really want to, you can try this to call Except on object variables by reflection:

```
// x and y are your object variables of the collections, 
// argumentType is the generic type you determined
  var methods = from m in typeof(Enumerable).GetMethods(BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.Public)
              where m.ContainsGenericParameters
              && m.Name == "Except"
              && m.GetParameters().Count() == 2
              && m.GetParameters()[0].ParameterType.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(IEnumerable<>)
              && m.ReturnType.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(IEnumerable<>)
              select m;
  var method = methods.First();
  IEnumerable things = method.MakeGenericMethod(new Type[] { argumentType }).Invoke(null, new [] { x, y }) as IEnumerable;
```

Comment: Non-generic `ICollection` does not implement generic `IEnumerable<T>`

Comment: The generic ICollection<T> does. The brackets were just missing ;)

Comment: @Botz3000 i do this but i got this error: Unable to cast object of type 'System.Collections.Generic.List1[System.String]' to type 'System.Collections.Generic.ICollection`1[System.Object]'.` it's possible to do what you say?

Comment: Stop using ICollection<T>, you only need IEnumerable. Where do you get this error?

Answer (score 0):

You can't use `ICollection<some_type_determined_at_run_time>` - compiler will not be able to produce any meaningful code for it.

<strike>If types are related casting to `ICollection<Base_Class>` should work in 4.0</strike> - wrong... Such cast works for IEnumerable (as it has "out T" as type), but does not for ICollection.

Comment: What do you mean with Base_Class? Base_Class of who? Because i don't know what type will got in `argumentType`.

Comment: I somehow decided that if your collection contains types Derived:MyBase than you could cast it to ICollection<MyBase> from ICollection<Derived> which is not true - edited.

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't answer your question directly, but rather answers the question from our discussion in the comments:

> How can I call the Except method using reflection?

The Except method is not a member of `ICollection<T>`, which is why your GetMethod call returns null.  Rather, it is an extension method defined on the static type `System.Linq.Enumerable`.  To call it with reflection, you'll have to treat it as a static method.  Something like this:

```
// there are two overloads of Except and I'm too lazy to construct the type parameters to get the correct overload
var methods = typeof(Enumerable).GetMethods(BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.Public);
var exceptMethod = methods.Where(m => m.Name.Equals("Except") && m.GetParameters().Lengh == 2).Single();

object[] arguments = new [] { currentCollection, anotherCollection };
object items = exceptMethod.Invoke(null, arguments);
```

Here's Jon Skeet's "simple way" (C# 4.0 and later):

```
dynamic items = Enumerable.Except((dynamic)currentCollection, (dynamic)anotherCollection);
```

Comment: @ViniciusOttoni I forgot to change the BindingFlags argument after copy-and-paste.  It's fixed now.  I also forgot to add a call to `Single()`, which is also fixed.